# What do the color codes mean for file blocks?

Tags: utorrent

While using uTorrent 3.4 alpha I couldn't help but notice that file blocks have various colors, but what do they mean?

On the screenshot I painted some of the most often appearing colors, but there might be more.

[image]

Comment: I recently wanted to know what they meant also.  This information is located in the online documentation/manual for uTorrent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developers change these colors quite often throughout the various updates on the software. Here are the colors that you highlighted;

- **Neutral Green:** Downloaded and written to disk
- **Light Green:** Requested data from peers, about to be downloaded
- **Dark green:** ...No idea as of current moment
- **Orange:** Canceled Piece
- **Purple:** Downloaded but not written to disk

There you go :)

Comment: How is something downloaded by not written to the disk?

Comment: A couple ways... Could still be in the process of being writen, Could be in the RAM waiting to be written, or could be in the the HDD cache waiting to be written as well

Answer (score 10):

A more correct description of colors:

- Grey: To be downloaded
- Purple: Requested from peer, awaiting download
- Dark green: Requested from multiple peers
- Light Green: Downloaded, not flushed to disk
- Neutral Green: Downloaded and written to disk
- Orange: Canceled Piece